# Why is the login not working in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a user in the database, and the hash password is stored there, why does the login not work when logging in?

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Privacy", "Home");
    }
}
```

---

```
builder.Entity<User>()
            .HasData(new User
                         {
                             FirstName = "Andrij",
                             LastName = "Matviiv",
                             Email = "blalbalal@gmail.com",
                             PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(null, "Andrew13mtv@")
                         };
```

This action method doesn't work even though I type correctly, how to fix?

Comment: You can try to add the user into `HashPassword(user, "Andrew13mtv@")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the method PasswordSignInAsync takes the username as a first parameter and you are passing email. try giving the username.

```
public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync (string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
```

for reference [click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.passwordsigninasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

and if you want to log in with email try this [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675750/asp-net-mvc-login-by-email-instead-of-username)

**Updated**

One more thing try specifying the user in the first parameter

```
    User user = new User
    {
        FirstName = "Andrij",
        LastName = "Matviiv",
        Email = "blalbalal@gmail.com",
    };
    var hashedPassword = hasher.HashPassword(user, "Andrew13mtv@");
    user.PasswordHash = hashedPassword;
    builder.Entity<User>()
        .HasData(user);
```

if the problem still occurs after passing the user as a parameter then plz try the above method of login with username otherwise try this to change the default login method to email. [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675750/asp-net-mvc-login-by-email-instead-of-username)

Comment: I don't know why, but I've tried everything and everything doesn't go into this if

Comment: maybe the problem is still in the password?